# Facebook Graph API: How to get missing page likes e.g. sports and interests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an unexpected behavior with the Facebook Graph API when trying to get all page likes from a person. Especially I have this problem with the liking of sports or interests.

For example, if a person likes "Basketball" (https://www.facebook.com/pages/Basketball/108614982500363?fref=ts) it is listed on his Facebook profile. But if I request the likes via the Graph API (`me/likes?limit=1000`) I receive all page likes except sports like "Basketball". Same problem with interests like "Swimming Pools" (https://www.facebook.com/pages/Swimming-pool/111986155484302?fref=ts).

For test purposes I use the following access permissions. In my opinion there is no necessary permission missing.

`public_profile,
    user_friends,
    email,
    user_about_me,
    user_actions.books,
    user_actions.fitness,
    user_actions.music,
    user_actions.news,
    user_actions.video,
    user_birthday,
    user_education_history,
    user_events,
    user_games_activity,
    user_groups,
    user_hometown,
    user_likes,
    user_location,
    user_managed_groups,
    user_photos,
    user_posts,
    user_relationships,
    user_relationship_details,
    user_religion_politics,
    user_status,
    user_tagged_places,
    user_videos,
    user_website,
    user_activities,
    user_work_history`

If I use the sports field of the user object (`me?fields=sports`) I get an empty response.

Unfortunately `me/interests` is deprecated since V2.3.

I have this problem only with sports and interests, but there may be other page categories affected.

How can I solve this problem to get this page likes as well?

---

### Edit: Additional Tests

I was able to confine the problem. It has to do with the time the like was created.

I am testing with two accounts:

- (A) created in 2011
- (B) created in May 2015

For test purposes I use the following pages (both of category `Sport`):

- `Basketball` (.../pages/Basketball/108614982500363)
- `Running` (.../pages/Running/109368782422374)

**Account (A)**

Liked `Basketball` in January 2013 => visible via Graph API.

Liked `Running` in May 2015 => NOT visible via Graph API.

**Account (B)**

Liked `Basketball` in May 2015 => NOT visible via Graph API.

Liked `Running` in May 2015 => NOT visible via Graph API.

Both accounts definitely liked the same pages.

Can someone reproduce the problem?

Comment: I get the same behavior regarding `sports`, but I can see my recent like of a sport in the `likes`  as well. It just took some minutes until it was visible to the Graph API. I'd suggest you open a bug with Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ if you can reproduce the behavior you're describing

Comment: Maybe it really takes some time until it is visible via the Graph API. However likes of other pages are immediately visible. I will try it tomorrow again.

Comment: If you just added new permissions, Facebook has some very quirky behavior when it comes to caching login tokens.  Any time you change the permissions your app requires, immediately log into your test account, go to Privacy Shortcuts (top right) -> See More Settings -> Apps and completely delete your app authorization.  That way, the next time you try to use the permissions you'll get a completely refreshed access token.

Comment: @user3268305 I deleted the App and requested the permissions again. Unfortunately, it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Tobi After one day the mentioned page likes are still not visible via the Graph API.

Comment: @Steve Have you checked the permissions contained with the `/me/permissions` endpoint? If this persists, please open a bug with FB.

Comment: @Tobi I did. The permission `user_likes` is granted.

Comment: There is already an open bug concerning this problem: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457461817746932/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been fixed by Facebook. Likes of category Sport and Interest are visible now.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457461817746932/